# 3d surface plot with logarithmic x and y axis

Tags: pgfplots

What I need the surface of the function $(1/x)^(1/y)$ in the range of x:10^1 - 10^8 and y:10^1 - 10^5. The x and y axes are preferred to be in logarithmic scale.
I tried different approaches, but none of them seem to work. (see below what I tried).

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
    [
    scale = 1,
    xlabel = {x},
    xmin = 10, xmax = 100000000,
    ylabel = {y},
    ymin = 10, ymax = 100000,
    zlabel={z},
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
    view={45}{10},
    ]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=50,
domain=10:100000000,
domain y=10:100000,
]
{(1/x)^(1/y)};

%other approach
%\addplot3 [surf] gnuplot [raw gnuplot]{
%        set dgrid3d 50,50 spline;
%        splot "data.txt"; %
%        };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

PGFPlots samples the domain equally along a linear axis, but not along a logarithmic axis. To work around this, you can set

```
domain=1:8,
domain y=1:5
```

and then specify the plot using

```
\addplot3 [surf] (10^x, 10^y, {(1/(10^x))^(1/(10^y))});;
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
    [
    scale = 1,
    xlabel = {x},
    xmin = 10, xmax = 1e8,
    ylabel = {y},
    ymin = 10, ymax = 1e5,
    zlabel={z},
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
    xmode=log, ymode=log
    ]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=30,
domain=1:8,
domain y=1:5,
]
(10^x, 10^y, {(1/(10^x))^(1/(10^y))});


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. But if you calculate the case of (1/e5)^(1/e8), you get a value of about 0.99... 
On the graph you have a value of about 0.65. So Is this really right?

Comment: Nevermind, you just forgot to put in the z formula the '10^'.
So, the right solution is
   (10^x, 10^y, {(1/10^x)^(1/10^y)})
Thank you

Comment: @Dries_VB: Oops, you're right. I corrected my answer.

Comment: One question, Why does the shader=interp option doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @Dries_VB: It works for me (that is, it generates output that looks similar to the screenshot in my answer, without the gridlines and with a smooth colour gradient). Do you get an error message or incorrect output? What version of PGFPlots are you using? Do you compile using `pdflatex`?

Comment: Using sharelatex with pdflatex compiler. I get an error and output is a pink plane. Which version should I use?

Comment: @Dries_VB: I would recommend using the latest version of PGFPlots (1.12). The plot works on Overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/2368480yxtfrq#/6119808/