# How to change viewpoint when using logarithmic scale with pgfplots?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I want to display a surface, with 3 points sitting on it. I attempted to combine two posts, with partial success. If I change the viewpoint, I receive the upper figure. In this case the log scaling goes away, but it is close to what I wanted (except the balls in the mesh points). If I do not change the view point, I receive the bottom figure, where the logarithmic scaling is perfect, but the interesting surface section and the points are not visible. How can I change the viewpoint, while keeping the log scaling?

BTW: what is the best way of emphasizing how the 3D positions of these points relate to each other? Maybe some extra mesh lines on a surface? Or some projected lines to the corresponding coordinates?

[image]
[image]

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232070/3d-surface-plot-with-logarithmic-x-and-y-axis
%http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/mesh-plot/
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [view={105}{18}] %% Comment this out
    [
    scale = 1,
    ymin = 1e5, xmax = 1.1e7,
    ymin = 1e-8, ymax = 1e-5,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
        ztick={.2,.5,.8,1.0},
        ytick={1e-7,1e-6,1e-5},
colormap/jet,
    xmode=log, ymode=log
    ]

    \addplot3+[
    mesh,%scatter,%,samples=10
%   surf,
    samples=10,
    domain=5:7.1,
    domain y=-8:-5,
    ]
    (10^x, 10^y, {  1/(10^x*10^y+(1-10^y))});

\addlegendentry{Surface}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
        (2397824, 1.665e-7, 0.715) };
\addlegendentry{A}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (1572480, 2.09e-7, 0.753) };
\addlegendentry{B}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (10649600,33e-9,.742) };
\addlegendentry{C}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will be happy to remove this. You have closed the `]` of the axis options, which is why all the logarithmic stuff got ignored. Just replace `][` by a comma to arrive at

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232070/3d-surface-plot-with-logarithmic-x-and-y-axis
%http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/mesh-plot/
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [view={105}{18}, %% Comment this out
    scale = 1,
    ymin = 1e5, xmax = 1.1e7,
    ymin = 1e-8, ymax = 1e-5,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
        ztick={.2,.5,.8,1.0},
        ytick={1e-7,1e-6,1e-5},
colormap/jet,
    xmode=log, ymode=log
    ]

    \addplot3+[
    mesh,%scatter,%,samples=10
%   surf,
    samples=10,
    domain=5:7.1,
    domain y=-8:-5,
    ]
    (10^x, 10^y, {  1/(10^x*10^y+(1-10^y))});

\addlegendentry{Surface}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
        (2397824, 1.665e-7, 0.715) };
\addlegendentry{A}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (1572480, 2.09e-7, 0.753) };
\addlegendentry{B}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (10649600,33e-9,.742) };
\addlegendentry{C}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As for the question what the best way to indicate the location is, I don't know, but I feel adding thin lines that connect the lines with the bottom and drawing the surface last may help.

```
\documentclass[border= 5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232070/3d-surface-plot-with-logarithmic-x-and-y-axis
%http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/mesh-plot/
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [view={105}{18}, %% Comment this out
    scale = 1,
    ymin = 1e5, xmax = 1.1e7,
    ymin = 1e-8, ymax = 1e-5,
    zmin = 0, zmax = 1,
        ztick={.2,.5,.8,1.0},
        ytick={1e-7,1e-6,1e-5},
colormap/jet,
    xmode=log, ymode=log
    ]

    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
        (2397824, 1.665e-7, 0.715) };
    \draw[thin,gray]    (2397824, 1.665e-7, 0.715) -- (2397824, 1.665e-7, 0);
\addlegendentry{A}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (1572480, 2.09e-7, 0.753) };
    \draw[thin,gray] (1572480, 2.09e-7, 0.753)  -- (1572480, 2.09e-7, 0) ;
\addlegendentry{B}
    \addplot3+[only marks] coordinates {
    (10649600,33e-9,.742) };
    \draw[thin,gray] (10649600,33e-9,.742) -- (10649600,33e-9,0);
\addlegendentry{C}

    \addplot3+[
    mesh,%scatter,%,samples=10
%   surf,
    samples=10,
    domain=5:7.1,
    domain y=-8:-5,
    ]
    (10^x, 10^y, {  1/(10^x*10^y+(1-10^y))});

\addlegendentry{Surface}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]