# pgfplots 3D with log y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I need an log y-axis for my 3D-plot, but somehow it seems that the generated plot is also in the negative y-range (not the axis-labels, but the y-domain).
The y-domain seems to be -1:1 (in fact it is, but i thougt it should work because of the "10^y" -> y-domain=0.1:10 (see comment in the code)).

I used this post for my code:
[3d surface plot with logarithmic x and y axis](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232070/3d-surface-plot-with-logarithmic-x-and-y-axis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Plot 1 - lin y-axis,
Plot 2 - log y-axis (attempt)

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
[scale = 1,
xlabel = {$\sigma$},
xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
ylabel = {$\omega$},
ymin = 0.1, ymax = 10,
zlabel={$A$},
zmin = -40, zmax = 20,
colormap/viridis]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=40,
domain=-1:10,
domain y=0:10]
(x, y, {20*log10(1/sqrt(((1.40845*y)+(2*x*y))^2+(1+(1.40845*x)+x^2-y^2)^2))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot 1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[h!]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
[scale = 1,
xlabel = {$\sigma$},
xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
ylabel = {$\omega$},
ymin = 1e-1, ymax = 1e1,
zlabel={$A$},
zmin = -40, zmax = 20,
ymode=log,        %added ymode
colormap/viridis]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=40,
domain=-1:10,
domain y=-1:1]    %new y-domain (10^y in the next line) 
(x, 10^y, {20*log10(1/sqrt(((1.40845*y)+(2*x*y))^2+(1+(1.40845*x)+x^2-y^2)^2))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Plot 2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I expect something like this (Plot generated in Mathematica - with log y-axis):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you thought way to complicated. Just adapt `domain y` according to `ymin`/`ymax` and you get the desired result ...

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        view={50}{50},
        width=\axisdefaultwidth,
        height=5cm,
        xlabel={$\sigma$},
        xmin=-1, xmax=10,
        ylabel={$\omega$},
        ymin=1e-1, ymax=1e1,
        zlabel={$A$},
        zmin=-40, zmax=20,
        ymode=log,
        colormap/viridis,
]
        \addplot3[
            surf,
            samples=40,
            domain=-1:10,
            domain y=0.1:10,    % <-- adapted
        % (no need to use a parametric plot)
        ] {20*log10(1/sqrt(((1.40845*y)+(2*x*y))^2+(1+(1.40845*x)+x^2-y^2)^2))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you substitute every y per 10^y in the equation you can get a more similiar result, see this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
[scale = 1,
xlabel = {$\sigma$},
xmin = -10, xmax = 10,
ylabel = {$\omega$},
ymin = 1e-1, ymax = 1e1,
zlabel={$A$},
zmin = -40, zmax = 20,
ymode=log,        %added ymode
view={60}{45},
colormap/viridis]

\addplot3[
surf,
samples=100,
domain=-1:9,
domain y=-1:1]    %new y-domain (10^y in the next line) 
(x, 10^y, {20*log10(1/sqrt(((1.40845*(10^y))+(2*x*(10^y)))^2+(1+(1.40845*x)+x^2- 
(10^y)^2)^2))});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The rounded shape in the botton of the orange surface might be a Mathematica's capability to trim out the surface and make more continuous plots. Alternatively, using tikz you are able to achieve a desired shape of surface performing subtractions of other mathematical functions, like F(x,y,z)= G(x,y,z)-h(x,y,z)